# What do the various numbers mean on the Hawtio profile page

Tags: hawtio

Hawtio has a lovely view of a running Camel application but I can't find any information on what the numbers refer to on the profile page.

E.g. we see Mean, Min and Max.

What do these refer to? Processes per second? Throughput?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah these numbers are from Apache Camel, from the MBeans that Camel offers. You can see some details here:

- http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/api/management/mbean/package-summary.html

And yeah min / max / mean are what they say, eg the lowest / highest and average processing time.

Comment: Thanks. So are the times in milliseconds per message? Thats what they look to be.

Comment: yes all times are in millis. The tooltip shows a description, in the attributes tab, and the tooltip may say if the times are in ms or sec. On top of my head only the shutdownstrategy mbean has a timeout in seconds (its 300 by default)